# Can Reduce *really* not solve for x here?

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

Sometimes I get the feeling I'm just flailing blindly with Mathematica.  Is solving for $x$ in the equation
$$ \frac{\cosh (x/2)}{x} = \sqrt{2} $$
really beyond the scope of Mathematica?  I try to solve it with the command:

`Reduce[(1/x)Cosh[x/2] == Sqrt[2], x]`

and am met with

`Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.`

I get a feeling that I'm doing something very silly.  Cheers for any assistance!

Comment: I don't see any special functions in the question or the answers, I must say...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use

```
Reduce[(1/x) Cosh[x/2] == Sqrt[2], x, Reals]
```

or

```
Solve[(1/x) Cosh[x/2] == Sqrt[2], x, Reals]
```

the latter yields

```
{{x -> Root[{-E^(-(#1/2)) - E^(#1/2) + 2 Sqrt[2] #1 &,      0.75858229952537718426}]}, 
 {x ->  Root[{-E^(-(#1/2)) - E^(#1/2) + 2 Sqrt[2] #1 &, 5.4693513860610533998}]}}
```

For transcendental equations you may get with `Reduce` or `Solve` roots  represented symbolically by `Root` though  they are in general transcendental numbers, so their  values are written numerically beside the transcendental function written in the form of a pure function.

```
Plot[ (1/x) Cosh[x/2] - Sqrt[2], {x, -7, 7}, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {-4, 4}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

It should be emphasized that using domain specifications in `Reduce` or `Solve` you may still get messages of unsolvability of a given equation or a system (of eqations or/and inequalities), e.g.

```
Reduce[ x Cos[x/2] == Sqrt[2], x, Reals]
```

> ```
> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>
> Reduce[x Cos[x/2] == Sqrt[2], x, Reals]
> ```

even though for a slightly different equation you can get the full solution, e.g.

```
Reduce[x Cos[x/2] == 0, x, Reals]
```

[image]

In these two cases there is an infinite number of solutions, but the latter case is much easier, because a solution satisfies one of the two conditions : `x == 0` or  `Cos[x/2] == 0`. In the first case we need to restrict a region where we'd like to find solutions. There we find all of them with `Reduce` (as well as with `Solve`) if in a given region there is only  a finite number of solutions, e.g. restricting the domain to real numbers such, that `-25 <= x <= 25` i.e. adding a condition `-25 <= x <= 25` to a given equation (now we needn't specify explicitly the domain to be `Reals` because `Reduce[expr,vars]` assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically in inequalities are real):

```
sols = Reduce[x Cos[x/2] == Sqrt[2] && -25 <= x <= 25, x]
```

[image]

Defining

```
f[x_] := x Cos[x/2] - Sqrt[2]
```

we can easily check that `sols` are indeed the solutions :

```
FullSimplify[ f[ sols[[#, 2]]]] & /@ Range @ Length[sols]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

To extract only numerical values of the roots combined with zero we can do (see e.g. [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/interlacing-a-single-number-into-a-long-list/4751#4751)):

```
Tuples[{List @@ sols[[All, 2, 1, 2]], {0}}]
```

Now we can plot the function with appropriately marked roots and the specified domain :

```
Plot[ f[x], {x, -40, 40}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
             Epilog -> {Thickness[0.003], Darker@Red, Line[{{-25, 0}, {25, 0}}], 
                        PointSize[0.01], Cyan, Point /@ Tuples[{List @@ sols[[All, 2, 1, 2]], {0}}]}]
```

[image]

Here the dark red line denotes the domain of our interest, and the cyan points denote 
all roots of the function `f` in this region.

Comment: I guess it would have been nice for Mathematica to tell me it was having trouble solving for complex x... thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, there are some omissions, however I think both `Solve` and `Reduce` are really powerful functions.

Comment: @Artes Of course, Mathematica has found *exact* solutions here; those solutions are just expressed using `Root` objects.  If you plug one of those roots back into the function and use `FullSimplify`, you get *exactly* zero.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thank you for your remark, indeed the solutions were represented symbolically with `Root`, but I meant their values only numerically.

Comment: @GlenWheeler You may be interested in [this blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/) to make more sense of the solution that Mathematica returns.  You might notice that the solution is just a symbolic representation of the root of the equation you entered near two values.

Comment: @GlenWheeler May I ask if my answer satisfies your needs ?

Comment: Of course.  I have no idea why I didn't accept it sooner.

Comment: @GlenWheeler Ok, thanks. Although that would be a really broad issue if not restricted to a specific equation.

Answer (score 21):

All of these work:

```
f[x_] := Cosh[x/2]/x - Sqrt[2];

FindRoot      [f[x] == 0, {x, 1}]
N@FindInstance[f[x] == 0, x, Reals, 2]
N@Reduce      [f[x] == 0, x, Reals]
NSolve        [f[x] == 0, x, Reals]
N@Solve       [f[x] == 0, x, Reals]
```