# Why doesn't Mathematica solve $x=\cos\,x$ properly?

Tags: equation-solving

Why doesn't *Mathematica* solve `x == Cos[x]` properly?

Both `Solve` and `NSolve` fail with the message:

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

Comment: NSolve works when restricted to reals: `NSolve[x==Cos[x],x,Reals]` gives `{{x -> 0.739085}}`.

Comment: The ["Dottie number"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html) is not known to have an explicit closed form.

Comment: Strongly related: [Can Reduce *really* not solve for x here?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4694/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you might use:

```
InverseFunction[Cos]
```

> ```
> ArcCos
> ```

One can see that this is valid only over the interval (-1, 1) which is probably why Solve does not give an answer:

```
Plot[{Cos@x, ArcCos@x}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A few methods to find the intersection in the illustration:

```
N @ FindInstance[x == Cos[x], x]

N @ Reduce[{x == Cos[x], -1 < x < 1}, x]

FindRoot[x == Cos[x], {x, 0}]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 0.739085}}
>
> x == 0.739085
>
> {x -> 0.739085}
> ```

---

I would be remiss not to point out that my plot above is only looking at real values.  One can see that as implemented `ArcCos` *does* handle the full circle:

```
Plot[{Cos @ ArcCos @ x, x + 1}, {x, -20, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thx, I just wanted to know why Mathematica didn't know to use arccos...

Comment: Of note is that `Reduce[]` returns a `Root[]` object, which can then be evaluated to arbitrary precision.

Comment: @J.M. I get `x == Root[{-Cos[#1] + #1 &, 0.73908513321516064165}]` where the "Dottie number" has 20.6 digits of precision.  How can that be accurately evaluated to *arbitrary* precision? (Assuming that you mean arbitrary in the general sense.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The 0.739... in the argument is not used to compute the value of the root, only to isolate it from any other potential roots. In this sense, it is similar to the index for normal polynomial `Root` objects, as returned by say, Solve[x^5 -x-1 == 0, x]. Of course, the root can be computed to arbitrary precision using the `-Cos[#1] + #1 &`.

Comment: @TomWellington This answer gives more detailed discussion of the issue http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here/4697#4697

Comment: @Mark Thanks, I've been thinking about `Root` all wrong. <:-o

Comment: As @Mark says, you can treat the `0.739...` as a "proximity indicator"; you can thus read `Root[{-Cos[#1] + #1 &, 0.73908513321516064165}]` as "the root of the equation $x-\cos\,x=0$ in the vicinity of $0.739085\dots$". You can apply something like `N[#, 100] &` to it, and the internal algorithms will then compute the root to higher precision.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility :

```
FixedPoint[Cos[#] &, 0.5]

(* 0.739085 *)
```

Comment: You don't need `&`: `FixedPoint[Cos, 0.5]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I was aware of this but thought to make the answer easier to generalize.