# Why can't Mathematica solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Reduce *really* not solve for x here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here)

Why can't *Mathematica* solve this equation?

```
f[x_] := Exp[Cos[3*x]]
g[x_] := (1/3)*x^3 - x^2 + 2
Solve[f[x] == g[x], x]
(* Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >> *)
```

Comment: Use e.g. `Solve[f[x] == g[x] && Abs[x] < 10, x, Reals]`. For more detailed discussion of transcendental equations see e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here/4697#4697, a general issue of `Root` see e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768

Comment: You can still solve this equation without assuming `x` to be real, but then the system might be unable to prove that there were all solutions found. Assuming `Reals` one gets `5` solutions, while assuming `Complex` one gets `385` solutions.

Comment: thanks a lot! you saved my life right there :)