# Problem with solving an equation

Tags: equation-solving

I dont understand why Mathematica cannot solve this equation:

Solve[Log[x^2 + 5] + 0.5 x + 1 == 0, x]

I get this error message:

Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help. >>

Comment: The equation is too difficult, have a look at `FindRoot`.

Comment: Just use it this way `Solve[Log[x^2 + 5] + 1/2 x + 1 == 0, x, Reals]` and if you find some doubts read e.g. [Can Reduce *really* not solve for x here?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here/4697#4697) and [How do I work with Root objects?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768).

Comment: Thank, both solved the problem: FindRoot[Log[x^2 + 5] + 0.5 x + 1 == 0, {x, 0}] gives en nicest looking answer for some reason.