# NSolve/Solve with equations containing periodic functions

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I first tried this command:

`NSolve[(2 Cos[x] Sin[x])/x^2 - (2 Sin[x]^2)/x^3 == 0, x, Reals]`

which yields "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.". But when I change it to

`NSolve[{(2 Cos[x] Sin[x])/x^2 - (2 Sin[x]^2)/x^3 == 0, Element[x, Interval[{0.5, 10}]]}, x, Reals]`

I get all solutions of the given interval as long as the interval does not touch zero.

Even more puzzling, when using `Solve` without interval I get no solutions which was to expect but when I do

`Solve[{(2 Cos[x] Sin[x])/x^2 - (2 Sin[x]^2)/x^3 == 0, 
  Element[x, Interval[{1/2, 10}]]}, x, Reals]`

(the above with solve) I get

`{{x -> {\[Pi]}}, {x -> {2 \[Pi]}}, {x -> {3 \[Pi]}}, {x -> \
{Root[{-Sin[#1] + Cos[#1] #1 &, 
      4.4934094579090641753}]}}, {x -> {Root[{-Sin[#1] + Cos[#1] #1 &,
       7.7252518369377071642}]}}}`

which are pseudo solutions which are however often easier to work with.

So why do `Solve` and `NSolve` struggle with this kind of equation and how can I work with that when not expecting it?

Comment: It has been asked many times, so you should take a closer look at the `equation-solving` and `trigonometry` tags. I guess this is almost a duplicate of [Can Reduce *really* not solve for x here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here/4697#4697). See also [Solve symbolically a transcendental trigonometric equation and plot its solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54896/solve-symbolically-a-transcendental-trigonometric-equation-and-plot-its-solution/54935#54935)

Comment: "How can I work with that when not expecting it?" - this is in general some kind of art, you can master it with some practice and insight.

Comment: `f[x_] = (2 Cos[x] Sin[x])/x^2 - (2 Sin[x]^2)/x^3; `

The problem with `x = 0` is that `f[0]` is only defined in the limit:

`f[0] ` is `Indeterminate` but `Limit[f[x], x -> 0]` evaluates to `0`

Comment: @artes thanks for links -- those helped me