# Why can't this set of inequalities be solved with the methods available to Reduce?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

Take the following set of inequalities:

```
Reduce[
  {
    ys < Power[xs^a + ys^a - x^a, 1/a],
    0 < xs < 10000,
    0 < ys < 12000,
    0 < x <10000,
    xs < x,
    0 < a < 1
  },
  {xs, ys, x, a},
  Reals
]
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

But why? How can I make it solvable via `Reduce`?

I read this other thread: [Can Reduce *really* not solve for x here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here), and I understood that if you provide a specific domain, as I did, the system should become solvable even if it involves transcendental functions.

Comment: How is Pow defined?

Comment: I think you overstate the ability of `Reduce`/`Solve` over a compact domain. [This blog post](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/) indicates that for a single-variable holomorphic function, an equation can be solved over a compact domain. The situation for multivariate functions or ones that are not holomorphic is less clear to me. My experience is that some of them cannot be solved, so maybe not yours.  The function `z^a`, with `a`  a real variable and `z` a real or complex variable, is a common obstruction.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 Whoops, I thought that that is the standard [Power](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html) function. Yet, even after replacing `Pow` with `Power`, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, @MichaelE2.

Comment: From your first inequality it follows ` xs^a<x^a` in contradiction to `x<xs`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I messed up the 5th inequality. Fixed now. Should have been `xs < x`.

Comment: But I don't think that your inference is correct. Perhaps you meant `x^a < xs^a`? Even then, why would this follow from that inequality? As far as I can see, `x^a` can be bigger than `xs^a`, because `ys^a^1/a` = `ys^1/a^2` and `a` is lower than 1.

Comment: `ys^a^1/a==1` I think!

Comment: There is a typo in your fix : Should be xs<x (not x>a)???

Comment: @UlrichNeumann `ys^a^1/a` is not 1, but I was also wrong. `ys^a^1/a` is `ys^root(a,a)`. Re typo, yes, you are correct. I updated now.

Comment: Something can be done:`NMinimize[{a, ys < Power[xs^a + ys^a - x^a, 1/a], 0 < xs < 10000, 
  0 < ys < 12000, 0 < x < 10000, xs < x, 0 < a < 1}, {xs, ys, x, a}]` produces `{0.00912988, {xs -> 2426.64, ys -> 0.022711, x -> 5341.51, 
  a -> 0.00912988}}` and `NMaximize[...]` produces `0.32545, {xs -> 0.5, ys -> 0.5, x -> 0.5, a -> 0.32545}}`. Unfortunately, then `FindInstance[
 ys < Power[xs^a + ys^a - x^a, 1/a] && 0 < xs && 0 < ys < 12000 && 
   0 < x < 10000 && xs < x /. a -> 1/5, {xs, ys, x}, Reals]` is running for ages.

Answer (score 1):

If you change to non-powered variables {xs1,ys1,x1}, you get solutions for at least rational a of the form a = 1/( 2 b) with b being positive integers.

First get conditions for changed variables and then test your inequation.

```
{a = 1/Pi, 
red = List @@ 
Reduce[{xs^a == xs1, ys^a == ys1, x^a == x1, 0 < xs <  10000, 
  0 < ys < 12000, 0 < x < 10000, xs < x}, {xs, ys, x}, Reals] // 
 PowerExpand}

(*   {1/\[Pi], {0 < ys1 < 2^(5/\[Pi]) 3^(1/\[Pi]) 5^(3/\[Pi]), 
0 < x1 < 10^(4/\[Pi]), 0 < xs1 < x1, xs == xs1^\[Pi], 
ys == ys1^\[Pi], x == x1^\[Pi]}}   *)

Reduce[ys1^(1/a) < Power[xs1 + ys1 - x1, 1/a] && 
   And @@ red[[1 ;; 3]], {xs1, ys1, x1}, Reals]

(*   Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>   *)
```

With a = 3/10 you get "False". And so on. Let make a test function.

```
test := {a = Rationalize[RandomReal[{.06, .94}], 1/20], 
  red = List @@ 
Reduce[{xs^a == xs1, ys^a == ys1, x^a == x1, 0 < xs < 10000, 
  0 < ys < 12000, 0 < x < 10000, xs < x}, {xs, ys, x}, Reals]; 
Reduce[ys1^(1/a) < Power[xs1 + ys1 - x1, 1/a] && 
And @@ red[[1 ;; 3]], {xs1, ys1, x1}, Reals]}

Table[test, {20}] // TableForm
```

Result ( not shown here) indicates there are only solutions for a = 1/ (2 b) with b beeing positive integers. I leave it to you to prove this.

Graphics says the same.

```
Clear[a]; Manipulate[
RegionPlot3D[
ys < Power[xs^a + ys^a - x^a, 1/a] && xs < x, {xs, 0, 10000}, {ys, 
0, 12000}, {x, 0, 10000}] // 
Quiet, {a, {1/2, 1/E, 1/Pi, 1/3, 2/3, 1/4, 1/6, 1/8, 1/10, 1/12, 
1/14, 1/16, 1/18}}]
```