# Can't this inequality really not be solved with Reduce?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

Taking $\alpha$ as given, I am trying to understand/know under which restrictions on $n$, the following holds:
$$ 0 \leq n+\alpha W\left(-e^{\frac{-n}{\alpha}} \right) \leq 1.$$
i.e I want to solve for $n$ the following two inequalities: a) $0 \leq n+\alpha W\left(-e^{\frac{-n}{\alpha}} \right)$, and b) $n+\alpha W\left(-e^{\frac{-n}{\alpha}} \right) \leq 1$.
In addition, I know $\alpha >0$, that both $n$ and $\alpha$ are reals.

- I manage to get that a) is satisfied for $n\geq \alpha$,
  using: `Reduce[n+a*ProductLog[-E^(-n/a)]>=0, n, Reals]` which returns `(a<0&&n==a)||(a>0&&n≥a)`.
- However I struggle to find any solution for the inequality b). I have tried all of the following:

```
(* for convenience I first define the function *)
f[n_, a_] =n+a*ProductLog[-E^(-n/a)]

Reduce[f[n, a]<=1, n, Reals]
Reduce[f[n, a]<=1 && a>0, n, Reals]
Solve[f[n, a]<=1, n, Reals]
Solve[f[n, a]<=1 && a>0, n, Reals]
```

Which all return:

*"This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve/Reduce."*

Even though I specified the domain as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/can-reduce-really-not-solve-for-x-here).

Is the inequality in b) really not solvable for $n$? Could Anyone think of an alternative command or commands that would do the trick?

Thank you,

**EDIT:**

In my context, `f[n_, a_]`being strictly increasing in `n`, and also because I know that (due to the domain of the Lambert W function) we must have `n ≥ a` (on the graph of `f[n, a]`below, we see clearly that it is not defined otherwise), **even the solution for the equality to 1 would suffice me.**

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[n, a], {n, -1, 10}], {a, 0, 5, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: increasing in n]

Comment: Maybe: `Solve[f[n, a] == 1, n]` ?

Answer (score 7):

We can change variable.

```
f[n_, a_] = n + a*ProductLog[-E^(-n/a)];
f[n, a] <= 1 /. n -> t*a // Simplify
```

> `a (t + ProductLog[-E^-t]) <= 1`

so for `a>0` we just need to solve

`t + ProductLog[-E^-t]<=1/a`

Since

```
FunctionRange[D[t + ProductLog[-E^-t], t], t, y]
```

> `y > 1`

so `t + ProductLog[-E^-t]` is increasing and we find its inverse.

```
InverseFunction[Function[t, t + ProductLog[-E^-t]]][1/a]
```

> `t<=1/a + E^(-1/a)`

> `n/a<=1/a + E^(-1/a)`

> `n<=1+a* E^(-1/a)`

**Edit**

For a fixed `a>0`,both

```
f[n_, a_] = n + a*ProductLog[-E^(-n/a)];
Solve[f[n, a] == c, n]
InverseFunction[Function[n, f[n, a]]][c, a]
```

get

> `E^(-(c/a)) (a + c E^(c/a)`

means that `f[n,a]<=c` is solvatable.